# Array of method calls using thread

Tags: multithreading, winforms, delegates

I am using Windows Form Application. In that, I have a class, which consists of 5 different methods. All of them are filling private members from various sources using thread.

For that I am using following code snippet to call a method

```
Dim threadForMethod1 As Threading.Thread
threadForMethod1 = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Method1)
threadForMethod1.Start()
```

Now I want to add on / off switch for thread. By the way, If I off the switch all the methods should execute using main thread.

What is the best way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Class:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class ThreadHandler

    Dim t1 As New Thread(AddressOf M1)
    Dim t2 As New Thread(AddressOf M2)

    Public Sub M1()
        Thread.Sleep(3000)
        MsgBox("M1")
    End Sub

    Public Sub M2()
        Thread.Sleep(3000)
        MsgBox("M2")
    End Sub

    Public Sub StartAll()
        If t1.ThreadState <> ThreadState.Unstarted Then
            t1 = New Thread(AddressOf M1)
        End If
        If t2.ThreadState <> ThreadState.Unstarted Then
            t2 = New Thread(AddressOf M2)
        End If

        t1.Start()
        t2.Start()

    End Sub

    Public Sub StopAll()

        t1.Abort()
        t2.Abort()

    End Sub

End Class
```

To Use the above Class:

```
Private th As New ThreadHandler()

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    th.StartAll()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    th.StopAll()
End Sub
```